# Is there a java equivalent to SIGINT?

Tags: java, unix

I was reading [this post on the difference between SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGKILL, etc](http://programmergamer.blogspot.com/2013/05/clarification-on-sigint-sigterm-sigkill.html) which states:

> SIGKILL: Terminates a process immediately. This signal cannot be handled (caught), ignored or blocked. (The "kill -9" command in linux generates the same signal).
>
> SIGTERM: Terminates a process immediately. However, this signal can be handled, ignored or caught in code. If the signal is not caught by a process, the process is killed. Also, this is used for graceful termination of a process. (The "kill" command in linux if specified without any signal number like -9, will send SIGTERM)
>
> SIGINT: Interrupts a process. (The default action is to terminate gracefully). This too, like, SIGTERM can be handled, ignored or caught. The difference between SIGINT and SIGTERM is that the former can be sent from a terminal as input characters. This is the signal generated when a user presses Ctrl+C. (Sidenote: Ctrl+C denotes EOT(End of Transmission) for (say) a network stream)

This sounds to me like the java equivalent to `SIGKILL` is `process.destroyForcibly()`and the equivalent to `SIGTERM` is `process.destroy()`. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

But is there a java equivalent to `SIGINT`?

Comment: EDIT: Oh, you meant you need to control a process spawned with ```ProcessBuilder```. As far as I know you are right, but it is stated in the docs that ```this is implementation dependent``` so it is difficult to answer

Comment: SIGINT is usually only triggered directly from the keyboard in UNIX.  SIGTERM is usually used from other programs, and SIGKILL is generally generated by an administrator or the OS is shutting down and a program hasn't responded to SIGTERM.

Comment: There are no exact equivalents to what you want, and there is not platform independent solution, but to kill the process you may try to dig about the tool called pskill. My guess that we are talking about POSIX underneath, and not Windows. However, if you are running Windows you may use FindWindow to send a message to another Windows process/program. Another possibility is to use stacktrace of all the running threads, which will work for OSs that have jconsole.